# UnimplementedError: Fused conv implementation does not support grouped convolutions for now

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build a CNN model to recognise human sketch using the TU-Berlin [dataset](http://cybertron.cg.tu-berlin.de/eitz/projects/classifysketch/). I downloaded the png zip file, imported the data to Google Colab and then split the data into train-test folders. Here is the model:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu', input_shape = target_dims),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, kernel_size=4, strides=1, activation='relu', padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, kernel_size=4, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),

    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation = "relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_classes, activation= "softmax")
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs=10, validation_data=val_generator)
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
UnimplementedError:  Fused conv implementation does not support grouped convolutions for now.
     [[node sequential/conv2d/Relu (defined at <ipython-input-9-36d4624b896d>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1358]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

I would be grateful to any kind of help that will solve this issue. Thank you.

(PS - I am running Tensorflow 2.2.0 and no GPU)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had this same error using the facial expression recognition dataset, here's how i solved this same error.

From what i understand the dataset is gray color,
when you use `ImageDataGenerator` of tensorflow and `flow_from_directory` to generate the train and validation set,

you **need to specify the color_mode as grayscale or rgb** based on the dataset/images, here it will be 'grayscale',

in the model the first layer Conv2D the input_shape should be

`input_shape = (height, width, 1)`, 1 because its grayscale.

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar error, the problem was with the number of channels for my image and the number of channels I specified in the model. So check the number of dimension of your image and check the value specified in the input shape ensure they are the same

Answer (score 7):

Just mention the `color_mode="grayscale"` in flow from directory and check your model input `(height,width,1)`.

Answer (score 3):

Just as @grande_cifer said, the issue pops up from an incompatibility of number of image channel specified and correct number of channels of real images.

If you are not sure of the exact number of channel, I advice you specify 1 in your parameter target_dims, and forcefully convert all images when loading them to your net as grayscale, using the parameter *color_mode = "grayscale"* when loading the images to your net.

For more info, check keras online doc.

Answer (score 2):

You will find this error in 2 cases:

1. when the number of channels for your image and the number of channels you specified in the model are **not same** . Here the solution is to make them equal.
2. When you use `group` param of `Conv2D` from `tensorflow.keras` . Here they have not implemented it with the use of `group` param , which is Depthwise Convolution in real (use `tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D`).  For me the work around was `pip install tf-nightly==2.10.0.dev20220406` as this package also have some unimplemented keras APIs...as this was not mentioned anywhere when I encountered this error

I hope this is useful

Answer (score 0):

**SIMPLE EXPLANATION WITH SIMPLE SOLUTION**

The problem may be caused by the difference between the channels defined in the model and the actual number of channels in the dataset. I recommend explicitly converting the image to grayscale before feeding it into the model.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).