# How to train a Keras autoencoder with custom dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am reading [this tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/03/02/anomaly-detection-with-keras-tensorflow-and-deep-learning/) in order to create my own autoencoder based on Keras. I followed the tutorial step by step, the only difference is that I want to train the model using my own images data set. So I changed/added the following code:

```py
IMAGES = "/path/to/my/images"
SHAPE = (200, 200)
INIT_LR = 1e-3
EPOCHS = 20
BS = 32

(encoder, decoder, autoencoder) = ConvAutoencoder.build(SHAPE[0], SHAPE[1], 3)
opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
autoencoder.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=opt)

image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0 / 255)
train_gen = image_generator.flow_from_directory(
    os.path.join(IMAGES, "training"), 
    class_mode=None, target_size=SHAPE, batch_size=BS,
)
val_gen = image_generator.flow_from_directory(
    os.path.join(IMAGES, "validation"), 
    class_mode=None, target_size=SHAPE, batch_size=BS,
)

hist = autoencoder.fit(train_gen, validation_data=val_gen, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BS)
```

My images are normal `.jpg` files in RGB format. However, as soon as training starts the `fit()` method throws the following exception:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['conv2d/kernel:0', 'conv2d/bias:0', 'batch_normalization/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization/beta:0', 'conv2d_1/kernel:0', 'conv2d_1/bias:0', 'batch_normalization_1/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_1/beta:0', 'dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0', 'conv2d_transpose/kernel:0', 'conv2d_transpose/bias:0', 'batch_normalization_2/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_2/beta:0', 'conv2d_transpose_1/kernel:0', 'conv2d_transpose_1/bias:0', 'batch_normalization_3/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization_3/beta:0', 'conv2d_transpose_2/kernel:0', 'conv2d_transpose_2/bias:0'].
```

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: Is the `autoencoder` works normally, w/o your custom data set? (while following that tuts)?

Comment: in the tutorial it says that you should fit with # train the convolutional autoencoder
H = autoencoder.fit(
 trainX, trainX,
 validation_data=(testX, testX),
 epochs=EPOCHS,
 batch_size=BS), but you fit on the generators. In other words, i don't think that you provide the Y/target, which for autoencoder is the same as the input. So you should have fit(train_gen, train_gen, val_gen, val_gen, EPOCHS=[...]) but make sure that the generator provides images in same order if run twice

Comment: @Octav When I use your code like `fit(train_gen, train_gen, val_gen, val_gen, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BS)` I get the following error: "fit() got multiple values for argument 'epochs'".

Comment: autoencoder.fit( train_gen, train_gen, validation_data=(val_gen, val_gen), epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BS)

Comment: @Octav That leads to the following error: "`y` argument is not supported when using `keras.utils.Sequence` as input."

Comment: flow_from_directory returns this: A DirectoryIterator yielding tuples of (x, y) where x is a numpy array containing a batch of images with shape (batch_size, *target_size, channels) and y is a numpy array of corresponding labels. .... Your Y must be X also

Comment: thank you for helping me better understand your situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use class_mode="input" at the flow_from_directory so returned Y  will be same as X

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L867-L958

> **class_mode**: One of "categorical", "binary", "sparse",
> "input", or None. Default: "categorical".
> Determines the type of label arrays that are returned: -
> "categorical" will be 2D one-hot encoded labels, - "binary" will
> be 1D binary labels, "sparse" will be 1D integer labels, - **"input"
> will be images identical to input images (mainly used to work with
> autoencoders).** - If None, no labels are returned (the generator
> will only yield batches of image data, which is useful to use with
> `model.predict()`). Please note that in case of
> class_mode None, the data still needs to reside in a subdirectory
> of `directory` for it to work correctly.

Code should end up like:

```
image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0 / 255)
train_gen = image_generator.flow_from_directory(
    os.path.join(IMAGES, "training"), 
    class_mode="input", target_size=SHAPE, batch_size=BS,
)
val_gen = image_generator.flow_from_directory(
    os.path.join(IMAGES, "validation"), 
    class_mode="input", target_size=SHAPE, batch_size=BS,
)
hist = autoencoder.fit(train_gen, validation_data=val_gen, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BS)
```

Comment: Thanks, that kind of solved my issue. But now I get the following exception from `fit()`: "Fused conv implementation does not support grouped convolutions for now." Any ideas?

Comment: from some comment on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61796021/unimplementederror-fused-conv-implementation-does-not-support-grouped-convoluti, maybe you should check that the channels of your images  3 (as prepared in the model ConvAutoencoder.build(SHAPE[0], SHAPE[1], 3)), and not  greyscale (1 channel). From flow_from_directory, i see that the default is rgb, so it matches your Model's expectation... Maybe force that to be rgb and check if your raw images are greyscale and somehow flow_from_directory does not do what we expect.